# Does Rails has any methods for improving the count query performance of no association model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know if a model has a has_many association, we can use 'counter_cache'.

But if a Model has no association, which method can I use to improve count performance?

I looked in Google, but didn't find any helpful resources about it.

Comment: What would you be counting if there are no has_many associations? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I want to do so because I guess this will improve performance. But I'm not familiar with SQL, so I asked if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such thing as "counter cache" for ruby Array or Enumerables. However if you are faced upon a performance issue, you can create one yourself.

You could store somewhere an integer that you would increment / decrement when pushing / poping elements from your array.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not familiar with SQL. If I add a column for storing an integer of total numbers, and fetch the last one value, I see it will create a SQL Query like 'SELECT "lyrics".* FROM "lyrics" ORDER BY "lyrics"."id" DESC LIMIT 1'.     I want to ask, if it is better than run 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lyrics"' SQL Query?

Comment: A count query will perform better than a `select *`

Comment: Not sure a select count(*) will be faster than select * with LIMIT. I just benchmarked this `Ebook.benchmark { 100.times { Ebook.first.id } }` and `Ebook.benchmark { 100.times { Ebook.count } }` and it looks like the first one, which is equivalent to `SELECT `ebooks`.* FROM `ebooks` LIMIT 1` is faster.

Comment: I did this on mysql with INNODB as engine.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm sure they are plenty of explanations and edge case to think of. I would then argue as a general rule of thumbs to make a `COUNT` query when we need to count on objects.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't get your question very well but I suggest checking out this rails cast on model caching.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-model-caching-revised